# AngularJs direct infinite Scrolling not working

Tags: angularjs, infinite-scroll

I ve got this view with a ng-repeat :

```
    <div style="overflow: auto; max-height: 550px; min-height:550px;"  >
        <table  class="table table-bordered table-hover  " border="1"  >
            <thead fix-head>
                <tr>  
                    <th>Photo</th>
                    <th>Identifiant</th>
                    <th>Prénom</th>
                    <th>Nom</th>
                    <th>Editer</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody >
                <tr ng-repeat="footballeur in footballers| limitTo: limit "   >
                    <td><img ng-src="img/{{footballeur.photo|| 'defaut.png'}}"/></td>
                    <td>{{footballeur.identifiant}}</td>
                    <td>{{footballeur.prenom}}</td>
                    <td>{{footballeur.nom}}</td>
                    <td><button ng-click="modifier_footballeur(footballeur)" class="btn btn-primary" aria-label="Left Align">Editer</button></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
    </table>
<button ng-click="loadMore()">more</div>
```

And in my controller :

```
$scope.loadMore = function() {
    $scope.limit += 5;
};
```

The button "more" works very well, so i'm adding 5 footballers to the ng-repeat each time i click on it. 
The problem is that i want to detect the end of the div bottom, and start loadMore() each time i reach the bottom.
I've tried 3 directives and full Jquery nothing works and ingnite the loadMore() correctly..

The Jquery detects well the bottom of the div , but refuses to execute loadMore() inside its function even with angular.element syntax...

This next directive detects well the end of the div, but i dont know how to start $scope.loadMore() from it, it doesn't recognize the scope. . Maybe you should have an idea ? thanks a lot :

```
monApp.directive("scrollable", function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var container = angular.element(element);
      container.bind("scroll", function(evt) {
          if (container[0].scrollTop <= 0) {
              alert('On the top of the world I\'m singing I\'m dancing.');

          }
          if (container[0].offsetHeight + container[0].scrollTop >= container[0].scrollHeight) {
              alert('On the bottom of the world I\'m waiting.');
              $('#liste').scope().loadMore();
          }
      });
    };
  })
```

Comment: Why is the code trying to extract the scope from the `#liste` element when scope is already available as an argument to the linking function?

Comment: try to read this [article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1173869/ng-repeat-performance-degradation-at-case-of-very)